# How can I add specific css id to parent menu with php or javascript

Tags: php, css, html

We are developing a menu which is taking datas from mysql.

DB Structure;

```
id  | name      | link      |   parent_id   
-----------------------------------------
1   | Home      | p.php     |   0
2   | Portfolio | p.php     |   0
3   | Projects  | p.php     |   0
4   | Contact   | p.php     |   0
5   | Web Design| p.php     |   2
6   | Grap. Desg| p.php     |   2
.
.
.
14  | Quote     | p.php     |   6 
.
-----------------------------------------
```

PHP and PDO;

```
<?php
$baseUri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$menuHtml='';
function createMenu($parentId){
    global $baseUri;
    global $menuHtml;
    global $db;
    $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM menu_options WHERE `parent_id` = ?');
    $query->bindParam(1, $parentId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
    $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
    if ($rowCount == 0) return;
    if ($parentId == 0)
        $menuHtml.="<ul id=\"menu\">\r\n";
    else
    $menuHtml.='<ul>';
    while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    {
        $menuHtml.='<li><a href="'.$row->url.'">'.$row->name.'</a>';
        createMenu($row->id);
        $menuHtml.='</li>';
    }   
$menuHtml.='</ul>';
return $menuHtml;
}
echo createMenu(0);
?>
```

And HTML Result;

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="articles.php">CORPORATE</a>
        <ul style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
            <li><a href="article.php?i=1">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?i=1">Mission Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="project2.php">Company Tag</a></li>
            <li><a href="project2.php">Production</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class=""><a href="projects.php">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
            <li><a href="project4.php">Meltblown</a></li>
            <li><a href="support.php">Spunbond</a></li>
            <li><a href="quote.php">Sms &amp; Smms</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Composites</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="articles.php?i=1">QUALITY</a></li>
     <li><a href="articles.php?i=1">NEWS</a></li>
     <li><a href="gallery.php">GALLERY</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

We think some kind of if else statement with `$baseUri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` but it doesnt solve our problem. We want to add a css class with PHP for Eg.; 
If we are in index.php Menu must look like;

```
<ul>
        <li><a class="current" href="index.php">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="articles.php">CORPORATE</a>
```

We have submenus, and those submenus has parent menu. We want to add specific CSS class to only `parent_id = 0`. If a submenu's parent menu is bigger than 0 it should be look up parent menu's parent menu. It's a little bit complicated and we are confused.

Comment: I would create an array of sub menu and than use a condition with a function called `in_array()` which accepts two parameters, one, the value you want to search in the array, and the second parameter as the array of sub menus where your value will be searched..

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thank you for comment. Can you show me a sample code to understand your algorithm logic please?

Comment: Am not much cleared with your question hence I didn't answered, can you clarify that, do you want to highlight the parent menu if one of your child menu is active? also, do you want to add another active class to the sub menu as well?

Comment: @Mr.Alien we want to higlight only parent menu if submenu or parent menu's link is on address bar. Thank you.

Comment: May I suggest a JavaScript solution?

Comment: @hex494D49 of course if it'll solve my problem.

Comment: Well, take a look at this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/letapebe/1/edit?html,js,output) and if you find it useful I'll paste it below as an answer :)

Comment: Also, I think instead of `$baseUri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` it should have been `$baseUri == $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` in the if statement...

Comment: @hex494D49 thank you for fiddle, but it's now higlighting in index.php both -> HOMEPAGE, PRODUCTS. I'm not familiar of javascript, how can i solve it? And also i want to add an `id` not `class` to target <li> :) Sorry for the topic of question i mentioned as css class.

Comment: @malte what do you mean with that?

Comment: if you have a statement `if ($baseUri = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) { /*do stuff*/}` then the `$baseUri` will be assigned the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and , since the assignment succeeded, the if statement will evaluate to true and will always go to the part where 'stuff gets done'. if you want to compare the value of `$baseUri` to the value of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`, you need to use two equal signs `==`

This might be why it didn't work...?

Comment: @hex494D49 everything fine, but it's always rendering PRODUCTS menu highlight. If you can solve it i'll accept as answer because it's solving my problem :)

Comment: Just tell me please what's the structure of your relative links? I believe you'll use relative links on your menu, right? And I'll test it on my production server in a couple of minutes. I mean, are your links like these in this menu or something like /products/food/some

Comment: $hex494D49 actually they are ugly url's. And some kind of parent menu's has same submanu links for eg: HOMEPAGE = index.php, CORPORATE = article.php?i=1, PRODUCTS = article.php?i=3, CONTACT = contact.php. I use same page template for all of pages without index and contact. and all them calling article.php

Comment: Check this out [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/qodubeha/1/edit?html,js,output) Just tested on production server and works just great. Have in mind that this version isn't for jsBin.com so upload it on your live server.

Comment: Any feedback, have you managed to solve the issue using my snippet?

Comment: Actually your snippet works fine but still higlighting whole parent menus because of same page = articles.php. I am looking for a solution with rewrite to solve the issue

Comment: Hm, it works perfectly here :) It must be an issue with your menu. Could you please update your question with real links and I'll check it again 'cause it's just sad to not use such a cool snippet ;) And please, use @ to quote me so I can see your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a **p** parameter in your URLs, representing the parentId

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.php?p=0">HOMEPAGE</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="articles.php?p=1">CORPORATE</a>
        <ul style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
            <li><a href="article.php?i=1&p=1">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="article.php?i=1&p=1">Mission Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="project2.php&p=1">Company Tag</a></li>
            <li><a href="project2.php&p=1">Production</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class=""><a href="projects.php?p=2">PRODUCTS</a>
        <ul style="visibility: hidden; display: none;">
            <li><a href="project4.php?p=2">Meltblown</a></li>
            <li><a href="support.php?p=2">Spunbond</a></li>
            <li><a href="quote.php?p=2">Sms &amp; Smms</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Composites</a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li><a href="articles.php?i=1&p=3">QUALITY</a></li>
     <li><a href="articles.php?i=1&p=4">NEWS</a></li>
     <li><a href="gallery.php?p=5">GALLERY</a></li>
     <li><a href="contact.php?p=6">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
```

And then in your PHP you write this :

```
$page=-1;
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
    $page = htmlspecialchars($_GET['p']);
}
```

and later in the code when you add your `<li>` elements, you write that 
(note the add of **theClassYouWantToAdd**)

```
if($parentId == $page){
    $menuHtml.='<li class="theClassYouWantToAdd"><a href="'.$row->url.'">'.$row->name.'</a>';
} else {
    $menuHtml.='<li><a href="'.$row->url.'">'.$row->name.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer. But now all parent menu's are higlighted.

Comment: I don't know how you handle your parents and row id so I just wrote `if($parentId == $page)` but you need to modify this condition according to what values you use in your database

Comment: I handle parents with `$parentId` but i dont know why it's happening.

Comment: Show the html output that you get by running the new php code